# Finite sample concentration results for partial correlation

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval

Let $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_p) \sim F$ be a multivariate random vector. We have n iid observations from F, $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Let $\hat r_{ab}$ be the empirical estimate of the partial correlation between $X_a$ and $X_b$ given all the other components of F.

What results are known for $P[|\hat r_{ab} - r_{ab}| > t] \leq f(t)$ where $r_{ab}$ is the population partial correlation and $f(t)$ is some decreasing function of t? What if $F$ is multivariate Gaussian? References would be welcomed.